# How to use Google APIs Client Library for .NET to get a new Refresh Token after it has expired?

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to find a solution for getting a new Refresh Token after the existing one has expired.
The [Google APIs Client Library for .NET Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#credentials) provides this hint:

> Both `UserCredential` and `ServiceAccountCredential` implement `IConfigurableHttpClientInitializer` so you can register each of these as:
>
> - An unsuccessful response handler, so it will refresh the token if it receives an HTTP 401 status code.
> - An interceptor, to intercept the Authorization header on every request.

Did anybody figure out how to register `UserCredential` as an unsuccessful response handler and make it handle the 401s automatically?

Answer (score 0):

By setting the HttpClientInitializer on the BaseServiceInitializer the library does all the magic for you (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Drive.Sample/Program.cs?repo=samples#106) - it refreshes the token when it expires.